Orbifold fundamental groups of a class of 2-orbifold
I am trying to compute orbifold fundamental groups of all 2-dimensional closed orbifolds. (I had thought this was a basic result, but I didn't find any articles that gave a description.)
Let $(\mathcal{G},X)$ denote a orbifold, where $\mathcal{G}$ is a groupoid and $X$ is the underlying space. A basic class of orbifolds I am thinking about is, the underlying space $X$ is a polygon with an interior point removed, and the local groups of edges are reflection $\mathbb{Z}_2$, of vertices are dihedral groups $D_{2n}$.
I compute a rather simple case. Let $\widetilde{X}=\mathbb{R}\times [-1,1]$, and $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$. The $\mathbb{Z}$ part of $\Gamma$ acts on $\widetilde{X}$ by $n\cdot (x,y) \mapsto (x+n,y)$, and the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ part acts as reflection about $x$-ray. Let $X=\widetilde{X}/\Gamma$ . Then the orbifold fundamental group of $(\mathcal{G},X)$ is $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$.
Since in general, an obifold can not be viewed as the (global) quotient space of a simply connected space, I am trying to compute the orbifold fundamental group of the above orbifold by Seifert-van Kampen theorem. One can find Seifert-van Kampen theorem for  orbifolds in Bridson, M. R., & Haefliger, A. (2013). Metric spaces of non-positive curvature (Vol. 319). Springer Science & Business Media. page 608.
Let $(\mathcal{G},X)$ denote the orbifold described before. Let $\widetilde{A}=\widetilde{X} \setminus \mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$, $\widetilde{B}=\cup_{p\in \mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}}B(p,\frac{1}{4})$ (here $B(p,r)$ means the open disc disc with point  as the center and  as the radius). Let $\widetilde{C}=\mathbb{R}\times \left([-1,-\frac{1}{4}) \cup (\frac{1}{4},1]\right)$, $\widetilde{D}=\bigl(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z} \bigr)\times(-\frac{1}{2} ,\frac{1}{2})$. Let $A,B ,C,D$ denote the correspoing quotient space. Let $(\mathcal{G}_A,A)$ denote the restriction of orbifold structure $(\mathcal{G},X)$ on $A$ and similarly for $B,C,D$.
By applying Seifert-van Kampen theorem and homotopy theorem, we can get $\pi_1(\mathcal{G}_A,A)\cong \pi_1(\mathcal{G}_C,C) * \pi_1(\mathcal{G}_D,D)=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}_2$ (omit base point). Again, applying Seifert-van Kampen theorem to $(\mathcal{G},X)=(\mathcal{G}_A,A)\cup (\mathcal{G}_B,B)$, one can get the orbifold fundament group of $(\mathcal{G},X)$.
Let $\widetilde{E}=\widetilde{A}\cap \widetilde{B}$. Then $\pi_1(\mathcal{G}_E,E)=\mathbb{Z}_2\langle e_1 \rangle * \mathbb{Z}_2 \langle e_2 \rangle $, where $\mathbb{Z}_2 \langle e_i \rangle$ denote the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ whose generator is $e_i$. Let $\pi_1(\mathcal{G}_A,A)=\mathbb{Z}\langle a_1 \rangle * \mathbb{Z}_2 \langle a_2\rangle$ and $\pi_1(\mathcal{G}_B,B)=\mathbb{Z}_2\langle b \rangle$. Let $l_1:\pi_1(\mathcal{G}_E,E)\to \pi_1(\mathcal{G}_A,A)$ and $l_2 :\pi_1(\mathcal{G}_E,E) \to \pi_1(\mathcal{G}_B,B)$ be group homomorphisms induced by inclusion.
By observing the corresponding loop of the element in orbifold fundamental in $\widetilde{X}$, we can see that if we let the $l_1(e_1)=a_2$, then $l_1(e_2)=a_1^{-1}*a_2*a_1$. Since $l_2(e_1)=l_2(e_2)=b$, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\pi_1(\mathcal{G},X)=&\pi_1(\mathcal{G}_A,A)*\pi_1(\mathcal{G}_B,B) / \langle l_1(e)l_2^{-1}(e) \mid e\in \pi_1(\mathcal{G}_E,E)\rangle \\ 
=& \mathbb{Z}\langle a_1 \rangle * \mathbb{Z}_2 \langle a_2\rangle * \mathbb{Z}_2\langle b \rangle / \langle l_1(e)l_2^{-1}(e) \mid e\in \pi_1(\mathcal{G}_E,E)\rangle \\ 
=&\langle a_1,a_2,b \mid a_2^2=1=b^2,\ a_2=b, \ a_1^{-1}*a_2*a_1=b\rangle \\
=& \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
What makes me confused is the bold part. Without the help of the global quotient $\widetilde{X}\to X$, how can we determine the images of $e_1$ and $e_2$ under the inclusion $l_1$?

I don't have time at the moment to properly answer your actual question, but in general when you have a quotient by a discrete group acting nicely, it will be an extension of $\Gamma$ by $\pi_1(X)$ coming more or less from the fibration $X \to (X \times EG)/G \to BG$ which works from the perspective of groupoid classifying spaces.

@AndresMejia Thank you for your comment. I know that the orbifold fundamental groups can be calculated by the method you mentioned. But I am trying to compute orbifold fundamental groups of all 2-dim orbifolds, not just nice orbifolds. Besides, it seems to me, the fibration can't provide enough information to compute orbifold fundamental groups, unless $X$ is simply connected.  I thought compute by Seifert-van Kampen theorem will be a direct way.
I compute the example in this question as a start, and I find that I can't get some information 'locally', which is the bold part in the question.
